# Angular route does not

Tags: angularjs

I want to route my parent application with sub-application in the project folder

So I notice the URL Changes but didn't display the page I navigate to

Case of study of the issue m facing

Localhost4020/Super
If I want to navigate to Login 
The URL change to Localhost4020/Super/Login 
But the login page won't show

Answer (score 0):

Check first your Login page code. Probably you have some errors causing the page don't showed. Although your code is compiled you may have errors only showed in the console of your browser: try F12 to show it...

Comment: Honestly, no error in my console I don't just know why the page is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your component file? If yes then pls share your code.

Comment: Okay   I will send it as zip file